# Jetty 9 to 11 upgrade requires servlet 5.0. Latest spark-java still using servlet 3.0

Tags: servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, spark-java

Hi we're on our way to upgrade to jetty 11 and have come across this issue - Jetty 11 needs servlet 5.0 while spark-java even upto 2.9.4 is still using servlet 3.0. I could not find any info related to this on the spark-java page. Does anyone have any information on the planned upgrade or such ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been no work on spark-java to upgrade past Servlet 3.0.

There has been forks of spark-java for that though.

See

- https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/1266